# Convert date format of file name

Tags: powershell

I have files that have a date in them, but the format is not correct for the process down stream.
current format is "name_yyyy_mm_dd_HH_mm"
needs to be "name_ddmmyyyyHHmm"
The current format is "N999AN__2021_04_14_18_43_.pak"
I need to modify it to N999AN_140420211843.pak

I have tried several things, but nothing is changing the name. This is my latest attempt.
What am I doing wrong?

```
$items = Get-ChildItem "$LTemp\*.txt"

foreach ($item in $items)
{
    Rename-Item –path $item.Fullname –Newname {("{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}_{4}_{5}" -f $item.name.split('_',6)[0,3,2,1,4,5])+$item.extension}

    write-host "Name is $item"
}
```

Comment: This question needs some clarity. Your examples are not consistent. You want this format `name_ddmmyyyyHH_mm`, but you say that you need to modify `N999AN__2021_04_14_18_43_.pak` to `N999AN_140420211843.pak` which doesn't respect the format. Which way is it? Consider giving a clear example.

Comment: Your example name has a double underscore before the year, is that a typo? It also has an underscore immediately before the extension, is that another typo? Please try to give accurate examples and expectations. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67478167/edit) your question to address these issues, and add the clarity suggested by Vivere.

Comment: The curly braces ```{ ... }``` around your ```-newname``` parameter should probably be round braces ```( ... )``` - you're currently declaring a script block which gets converted to a literal string of the source code rather than evaluating an expression. Try assigning it to a temporary variable and using ```write-host``` so you can see what the value is...

Comment: You don't need redeclare the extension. That may be the actual problem here since you're formatting it

Comment: As others have said, your stated desired output pattern doesn't match your example, and neither of those remotely match what your output code would have. Also that you're asking to rename a bunch of *.pak files, but your actual example code enumerates *.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm operating under the assumption that you need to enumerate *.pak files, and that the expected input pattern is `name__yyyy_mm_dd_HH_mm` and that the output pattern is `name_ddmmyyyyHH_mm`. If that's wrong, you'll have to fix the code.

That said, scriptblocks don't really work well like you're doing. You're basically passing them as a value, and they don't always have a fixed value. You probably just want a group operator `()` or subexpression `$()`.

```
$items = Get-ChildItem "$LTemp\*.pak"

foreach ($item in $items)
{
    Rename-Item –path $item.Fullname –Newname (("{0}_{3}{2}{1}{4}_{5}" -f $item.name.split('_', [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries))+$item.extension) -WhatIf

    write-host "Name is $item"
}
```

I've added `[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries` here because you've got a double underscore in your described input pattern.

Personally, though, I would probably use a regular expression with named capture groups because then I could have Powershell complain when the pattern didn't match. Additionally, I tend to have fewer problems piping file objects to `Rename-Item` rather than feeding it an object.

```
$items = Get-ChildItem "$LTemp\*.pak"

$Pattern = '^(?<Name>.+)__(?<Year>\d{4})_(?<Month>\d{2})_(?<Day>\d{2})_(?<Hour>\d{2})_(?<Minute>\d{2})_'
foreach ($item in $items) {
    if ($item.Name -match $Pattern) {
        $NewName = '{0}_{1}{2}{3}{4}_{5}{6}' -f $Matches['Name'], $Matches['Day'], $Matches['Month'], $Matches['Year'], $Matches['Hour'], $Matches['Minute'], $item.Extension
        $item | Rename-Item -NewName $NewName -WhatIf
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "File '$($item.FullName)' does not match expected filename pattern '$Pattern'."
    }
}
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` parameter to actually perform work.

Comment: Thank you Bacon Bits. The top example was what I needed